# Docker exec command to create a file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-registry

0

I am trying to run this command and getting an error:

docker exec 19eca917c3e2 cat "Hi there" > /usr/share/ngnix/html/system.txt

/usr/share/ngnix/html/system.txt: No such file or directory

A very simple command to create a file and write in it, I tried echo and that one too didn't work.

Comment: (Do you mean to use a Dockerfile `COPY` directive to create the file in a reusable image?)

Answer (score 2):

The [`cat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) command only works on files, so `cat "Hi there"` is incorrect.

Try `echo "Hi there"` to output this to standard out.

You are then piping the output to `/usr/share/ngnix/html/system.txt`. Make sure the directory `/usr/share/ngnix/html/` exists. If not create it using

```
mkdir -p /usr/share/ngnix/html
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are trying to create the file in the container.

You have several problems going on, one of which @Yatharth Ranjan has addressed - you want `echo` not `cat` for that use.

The other is, your call is being parsed by the local shell, which is breaking it up into `docker ... "hello world"` and a `> ... system.txt` on your host system.

To get the pipe into file to be executed in the container, you need to explicity invoke bash in the container, and then pass it the command:

`docker exec 12345 /bin/sh -c "echo \"hello world\" > /usr/somefile.txt"`

So, here you would call /bin/sh in the container, pass it -c to tell it a shell command follows, and then the command to parse and execute is your `echo "hello world" > the_file.txt`.

Of course, a far easier way to copy files into a container is to have them on your host system and then copy them in using docker cp: (where 0123abc is your container name or id)

`docker cp ./some-file.txt 01234abc:/path/to/file/in/container.txt`

Comment: The copy worked great!  The echo did not, I had to change it by adding an extra quote to each side like this ```docker exec 12345 /bin/sh -c "echo \""hello world\"" > /usr/somefile.txt"```

Comment: oh gosh. double escape the strings. once for the local shell, once for docker.

Comment: `❯ docker run -d alpine tail -f /dev/null`
`1fd3...`
`❯ docker exec 1fd3 /bin/sh -c "echo \"hello world\" > /root/hello.txt"`
`❯ docker exec 1fd3 cat /root/hello.txt`
`hello world`
Works fine for me.

Comment: I was executing my command at a PowerShell prompt.  Perhaps it's really a PowerShell thing.

Comment: bash > cmd > powershell. :P